# I am finding issues while importing data from .csv to SQL

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a data set with following
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejqjI.png)
and the creation of table is as follows:

create database investi;
use investi;
CREATE table users(
user_id int,
created_at DATETIME,
company_id int,
language varchar(20),
activated_at DATETIME,
state varchar(20));

and while I import to the table it is showing:Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect datetime value: '01-01-2013 13:07' for column 'created_at' at row 1", 1292)

So i need on how to change the datetime default value removing seconds part.Any way on how to go about it?

Need help in how to do the changes and how to import .csv to sql

Comment: Could you please provide the example data as text instead off a image.

Comment: @RaymondNijland preferably in which format?
Link or text form

Comment: Consider https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html paying attention to the section Input Preprocessing